# How to use m3u file with LibVlc in android?

Tags: java, android, vlc, libvlc

I'm trying to implement an IPTV player in my android app so i saw that LibVlc supports this service. I have put an example to use the mediaplayer and it works using a single video url but now i would like to implement M3U files to add playlists. I've been searching but i don't find a good example or guide of how to achieve this.

This is my code now:

```
private void setVideoPlayer() {

        LinearLayout previousLayout;
        mLibVLC = new LibVLC(this);
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(mLibVLC);

        mVideoLayout = findViewById(R.id.layoutVlc);
        LinearLayout layoutTv = findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutTv);
        LinearLayout layoutGraph = findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutGraph);
        LinearLayout layoutTrack = findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutTrack);

        if(layoutTv.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
            previousLayout = layoutTv;
        }
        else if (layoutGraph.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            previousLayout = layoutGraph;
        } else {
            previousLayout = layoutTrack;
        }

        ImageView ivMediaPlayer = findViewById(R.id.ivVideoPlayer);
        ImageView ivExitMode = findViewById(R.id.ivExitTvMode);

        ivMediaPlayer.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            previousLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            layoutTv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mMediaPlayer.attachViews(mVideoLayout, null, ENABLE_SUBTITLES, USE_TEXTURE_VIEW);

            final Media media = new Media(mLibVLC, Uri.parse("https://www.rmp-streaming.com/media/big-buck-bunny-360p.mp4"));
            mMediaPlayer.setMedia(media);
            media.release();
            mMediaPlayer.play();
        });


        ivExitMode.setOnClickListener(v->{
            mMediaPlayer.detachViews();
            layoutTv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            previousLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        });

    }
```

How could i do it?

Answer (score 0):

M3U files are just text files with a list of URLs pointing to media files.

- Create a Media with the M3U URL,
- Parse it,
- Once parsed, access the sub items (those are the actual media URLs you want to play), like this `media.subItems();`
- Play any of the sub items by giving them to the mediaplayer.